# What is the best way to monitor subscribers to my ATOM feeds

Tags: php, xml, atom-feed

I have a bunch of ATOM feeds, some generated dynamically others not, and I would like to be able to monitor the subscribers to each one.

For the dynamic ATOM feeds, it is the same php file echoing different xml dependent on the $_GET data.

Can someone tell me an efficient way to monitor the subscribers to my feeds?

Comment: If you're not particularly averse to getting outside help, [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com) does a great job of monitoring subscribers for my feeds.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to parse your server logs. This is easy and requires no code modification. It can also be done offline and doesn't interfere with the site. You *do* have server logs, right?

Alternately, add some code to the feed generation to log request data.